# Single tree library which allows to move nodes

Tags: library, javascript

I'm looking for an already implemented tree javascript library (single-double singled list) like [arbolreal](https://github.com/afiore/arboreal) but which a feature which allows me to move nodes to upper levels and inner level.

Basically, I'm working on a to-do list, where I need to indent and outdent tasks, which means, moving nodes to inner or lower levels.

Any suggestions?